# Websphere commerce 7

Tags: websphere-commerce

Am working with websphere commerce 7 organization administration console. My is requirement is that some pages of orgadmin console sholud be read only to some roles.Need directions in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying SiteAdminConsole and add access based on roles. location is WC/xml/tools/adminconsole

Refer to CommerceAcceleratorB2C.xml in WC/xml/tools/common